# How to call component without call it (Vue)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to call component without import in my Vue files

**This files in Laravel Nova package**

404.vue files

```
<template>
   <error-404 />
</template>
```

Error404.vue

```
<template>
  <div
    class="fixed pin bg-40 z-50 flex items-center justify-center min-w-site p-6"
  >
    Error 404
  </div>
</template>
```

The `404.vue` and `Error404.vue` in the same folder or not

Comment: Are you saying you can't import the Error404.vue file in your 404.vue? Or are you saying you don't think you should have to?

Comment: Please clarify the question because it contains too few specifics. Maybe provide more source code, or show what's happening and what you don't want to happen?

Comment: This files is work in Laravel nova i need to do like this i need to call 404 without import